# How to go back to the superview in ios

Tags: ios, uiview

To view1 I added a sub view (view2). And now I am in view2, Now I wanted to move back to view1. I am using `[self.view removefromsuperview]` but it is not working.

Comment: What is `self.view`? You only described `view1` and `view2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't supposed to organise your application as views that you add on top of one another.  A more typical way of organising your application is to split the different screens into different view controllers and use a `UINavigationController` to navigate between them.

If you just lump all your code together into a single view controller and manually add and remove views, you're going to get into a mess very quickly.  I strongly recommend reading [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).